# Why does command not run after SetTimer?

Tags: timer, autohotkey

This code shows up the message box:

```
Msgbox, Hello

SetTimer, CheckTime, 1000 ; updates every 1 second
CheckTime:
Return
```

But this doesn't:

```
SetTimer, CheckTime, 1000 ; updates every 1 second
CheckTime:
Return

Msgbox, Hello
```

Why is that? I don't see anything special on the [SetTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script stops executing new lines whenever it finds the first `Return` keyword.

Everything after the first Top Level `Return` will be ignored as of initial execution, unless it has been called from above lines.

Look at this code piece:

```
MsgBox, I'll run!!!

MsgBox, Me 2!!!

Gosub, PastReturn

overPastReturn()

MsgBox, Me 5!!!

Return ; This is the first Top Level Return. Code Stops Executing Here.

MsgBox, Not Me!!!

PastReturn:
    MsgBox, Me 3!!!
Return ; This Return Belongs to PastReturn Label.

MsgBox, Not Me 2!!!

overPastReturn(){
    MsgBox, Me 4!!!
}
```

Comment: I see, but this is also weird, since you can have multiple separate `#If` functions and each of them require `return`. I have a whole script which has been using for years contains so many top `return`s

Comment: #If has nothing to do with `Return` keyword, it's context for hotkeys.
It's not weird. It acts as expected, many languages would act like this in the main thread.
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm

Comment: I still don't understand why after `return` the script should stop. [This example script](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/9tjwwi/detect_interaction_with_script_idle/e8x03bj/) has 3 top-level `return`s, yet it still works.

Comment: The only part that is autoexecuted on that script is:
`LastInteraction := A_TickCount` and `SetTimer, CheckIdle, 1000 ; Every 1 second`
The rest of the script is called by other means. Let's say you move the setTimer after the return; it will never be called. The space hotkey will still work though.